# Openedx import fails with "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data_dir'" message

Tags: openedx

I created a course on my personal openedx instance. Then exported it, and tried to import it into an institutional platform but got the error :

```
There was an error while importing the new course to our database.
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data_dir'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuotX.png)

**How to solve this ?**

---

Edit: also, duplicated sections are not exported properly. You must create them my click on the create button, then move relevant content into those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix some minor issue in the archive.

Within your archive, edit `/course/policies/course/policy.json`.

Somewhere within it there is a `tabs` object.

```
"tabs": [
      {
        "course_staff_only": false,
        "name": "Home",
        "type": "course_info"
      },
      {
        "course_staff_only": false,
        "name": "Course",
        "type": "courseware"
      },
      ...
]
```

Within it, the type `courseware` whould be first.

```
"tabs": [
      {
        "course_staff_only": false,
        "name": "Course",
        "type": "courseware"
      },
      {
        "course_staff_only": false,
        "name": "Home",
        "type": "course_info"
      },
      ...
]
```

Import then works :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlCvO.png)